# Image display error after changing dtype of image matrix

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm using opencv + python to process fundus(retinal images). There is a problem that im facing while converting a float64 image to uint8 image.

**Following is the python code:**

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

filename = askopenfilename()
a = cv2.imread(filename)
height, width, channel = a.shape
b, Ago, Aro = cv2.split(a)
mr = np.average(Aro)
sr = np.std(Aro)

Ar = Aro - np.mean(Aro)
Ar = Ar - mr - sr

Ag = Ago - np.mean(Ago)
Ag = Ag - mr - sr

#Values of elements in Ar
#    Ar = [[-179.17305527, -169.17305527, -176.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527],
#           [-178.17305527, -169.17305527, -172.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527],
#           [-179.17305527, -178.17305527, -179.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527],
#           ...,
#           [-177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527],
#           [-177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527],
#           [-177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527, ..., -177.17305527, -177.17305527, -177.17305527]]

Mr = np.mean(Ar)
SDr = np.std(Ar)

print "MR = ", Mr, "SDr = ", SDr

Mg = np.mean(Ag)
SDg = np.std(Ag)
Thg = np.mean(Ag) + 2 * np.std(Ag) + 50 + 12

Thr = 50 - 12 - np.std(Ar)
print "Thr = ", Thr
Dd = np.zeros((height, width))
Dc = Dd
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):

        if Ar[i][j] > Thr:
            Dd[i][j] = 255
        else:
            Dd[i][j] = 0

TDd = np.uint8(Dd)
TDd2 = Dd

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if Ag[i][j] > Thg:
            Dc[i][j] = 1
        else:
            Dc[i][j] = 0

#CALCULATING RATIO
ratio = 500.0 / Dd.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(Dd.shape[0] * ratio))
#
# #RESIZING TO-BE-DISPLAYED IMAGES
resized_TDd = cv2.resize(TDd, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized_TDd2 = cv2.resize(TDd2, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized_original = cv2.resize(Aro, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

cv2.imshow('TDd', resized_TDd)
cv2.imshow('TDd2', resized_TDd2)
cv2.imshow('Aro', resized_original)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`Ar[][]` has -ve as well as +ve values and `Thr` has a -ve value. **`Dd` is the image which i want to display.** The problem is that `TDd` displays a bizarre image *(255s and 0s are being assigned to appropriate pixels, i checked* but the image being displayed is weird and not similar to `TDd`

**Original image**

[image]

**Red channel image:**

[image]

**TDd (uint8 of Dd):**

[image]

**TDd2 (same as Dd)**

[image]

**Dd2 (declared uint8 dtype while initializing)**

[image]

Why are the `TDd` and `TDd2` images different? 
**Since the difference between the gray values of the pixels (as far as i understand and know) in these 2 images is only 255, 0 *(in TDd)* and 255.0, 0.0 *(in TDd2)***.

It would be a great great help if someone could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look I executed your code and there are the [results](http://postimg.org/gallery/1qi7dozn0)

They seem pretty normal to me... this is the exact [code](https://pastebin.com/6jwgKi9r) I used

Ar is different from the others because when you `imShow()` it, it puts white where values are > 0 black otherwise. The other matrices after tour code get white where > `Thr` which is less than 0, so more pixel get white obviously.

**update**

You assigned Dd to Dc when you should've done Dc = np.zeros((height, width)).

Comment: I have updated the code, there was a small snippet which i didn't add yesterday that was causing the discrepancy with your results and mine (i tried the old code and yes they were giving me the outputs same as yours). I am truly sorry for the inconvenience caused and thankyou so much for helping me! Could you please re-run the code now and tell me what the problem is?

Comment: The problem was a REALLY noob one. I assigned `Dd` to `Dc` when i should've done `Dc = np.zeros((height, width))`. I didn't know about the memory referencing in python! Now i feel stupid to make this mistake. I managed to solve it. If you update your answer with this, I'll accept it as the answer and upvote it as a thanks for all the troubles! Thankyou so much mate!

Comment: @hulkinBrain oh sorry I couldn't try your code before. Yes not that you mentioned it yes that's the solution. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when Images are represented with np float64 arrays, RGB values are in range 0 to 1. So when converting to uint8 there is a possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint8.

I would directly create Dd as a:

```
Dd = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Naah, even that didn't work. I forgot to mention this in the question. Would it help knowing that `Dd` is the red channel of a colored image. Since the red channel would be a grayscale image, it would be 8bit only. I have edited the question.

Comment: You changed the code in the question but there you still use Dd instead of Dd2. you did try it anyway right? So even if you use Dd2 in your code it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please show me an example of `print(Dd2)` and than of the value of `Thr`? With the informations i got now there is not much i can think of...

Comment: Yeah, i did try it,thanks for pointing it out though, i'll update the code. The purpose for which i wrote the _CODE TO CHECK IF ALL VALUES ARE EITHER 255 OR 0 ONLY_ was for this only i.e. to check whether the gray values at Dd2[i][j] are strictly 255 or 0 only. It isn't displaying anything, neither `boogie number` nor `-ve number` nor `too +ve` which means the values are either 255 or 0 only. Please ask if you need any more information and thankyou so much for helping!

Comment: I still don't know how to help you...can you post the results of prints and the values of variables you set like `Thr` and maybe a print of  `Ar` matrix?

Comment: @hulkinBrain Beacuse not having the images and not knowing the premises of the code I cannot even try the code myself, so I'm not able to help you

Comment: The original image that i have uploaded here is `Ar`. Gray values of the pixels are stored in `Ar`. I'll update the question to provide info about `Ar`.

Comment: The reason i'm refraining from adding the output of `Ar` is because its a huge matrix.

Comment: Well maybe even sone of the values?

Comment: I don't understan what you are doing with all that subtracting the mean value? Why don't you apply threshold directly on matrix Aro? obviously a new threshold specific for Aro

Comment: What i'm doing with all that subtraction is extracting the the bright colored round spot at the bottom left. Why i'm not directly applying the operations on `Aro` is that i need to preserve that image matrix for further use, that's why i'm using another variable `Ar`. So, if the value stored in the element `Ar[i][j]` is greater than that of the threshold `Thr`, 255 is stored at the corresponding pixel position `Dd[i][j]` and if not, 0 is stored. the resultant is the output image i.e. `TDd2`. See the updated question for respective outputs of `Ar` and `Thr`.

Comment: Look I executed your code and there are the results: https://postimg.org/gallery/1qi7dozn0/d613b198/

Comment: They seem pretty normal to me... this is the exact code I used : http://pastebin.com/6jwgKi9r

Comment: Ar is different from the others because when you imShow it, it puts white where values are > 0 black otherwise. The other matrices after tour code get white where > Thr which is less than 0, so more pixel get white obviously.